# RonR : Assets not working on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

I thought this issue would be ok with assetpipeline so I ran `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` then opened app on heroku but didn't work. My Gemfile is below. 
    ruby '2.3.0'

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5.1'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'jpmobile', '~> 4.2.3'
#this gem is for users functions
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
#js work on heroku by gem below
gem 'therubyracer'


group :development, :test do

  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do

  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end


group :development, :test do
     gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
     gem 'pg'
     gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

and productionrb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale shohinion use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like
  # NGINX, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = true
  config.serve_static_assets = true

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in shohinion.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false

  # required for heroku
  #note to set this to actual host ex: { host => 'xxxxx.com'}
  #config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }



  initializer :after_append_asset_paths,
  :group => :all,
  :after => :append_assets_path do
  config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'stylesheets', 'smart_phone')
  config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'javascripts', 'smart_phone')
end
end
```

I did assetspipeline commando in several ways but still didn't work. My Gemfile and production.rb are ok? If there are anything I should add or delete just teach me. I've heard this kind of issue basically comes from production.rb but I'm not sure. Just tell me if you need more files to check I will show it here.

Comment: Firstly, setting config.assets.precompile=true   IS THE FASTEST WAY TO SLOW DOWN YOUR APPLICATION'S PAGE RENDERING.  I can show you how to fix that after but for now, did you require the css and js files as necessary after including the gems?  If so, did you run bundle install to install all of the gems?

Comment: Add gem 'puma' to group :production

Comment: I did bundle install to install of the gems. I added gem 'puma' and pushed then checked heroku open but didn't work.

Comment: Do you know any solutions...?